# Rails partial inheritance hack

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a STI table and want to be able to render a collection using

```
render @collection
```

with every elements of the collection using their own partial or, if they don't have one, the parent partial. You know, partial inheritance.

So I added to my parent model :

```
def to_partial_path
  self.class._to_partial_path
end

protected

# a little hack to get partial inheritance in views, check if the partial exist, if not
# return the parent's one. Provide class level cache, be sure to restart your app when
# adding/removing partials.
def self._to_partial_path
  @_to_partial_path ||= begin
    element = ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore(ActiveSupport::Inflector.demodulize(self))
    collection = ActiveSupport::Inflector.tableize(self)
    if File.exists?(Rails.root.join('app', 'views', collection, "_#{element}.html.erb")) ||
    self.superclass == ActiveRecord::Base

      "#{collection}/#{element}"
    else
      self.superclass._to_partial_path
    end
  end
end
```

The original code is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d3d9a150a4ba1084cf28fd26be2a154f4540952/activemodel/lib/active_model/conversion.rb#L57).

This seems to work great so far but I want to have some opinions.

Should I have gone another way?

Are there any "gotchas" I might encounter doing it this way?

Any way to refactor this?

**edit**: No problem whatsoever, it's working great for now. I'm looking for a way to achieve something similar with form (ie render form in new and edit views render the `child _form` partial if their is one, the parent one otherwise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually looks pretty solid.

Another approach would be to **sub-class** the **[Renderer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer)** and make it responsible for retrieving the base classes' `to_partial_path`.

For me this feels a bit cleaner because it is **sub-classing versus monkey-patching** and because the renderer is supposed to find and load the template anyway while the model class shouldn't case about the (non-)existence of the view at all.

After looking at it for a while, I would the make sub-classes **[partial_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/PartialRenderer/partial_path)** check if the template exists and find the template of the base class if it doesn't.

Comment: How would you let Rails know that it should use the `PartialRenderer` subclass? Is their a hook for that (I haven't found one)?